# How can I make service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType using java code

Tags: java, geoserver, geotools

I am trying to fetch details of a particular layer by executing below code in GeoServer and have to perform some CQL operation

```
String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeNames=districtwpc:ernakulam";
Map<String, Serializable> connectionParameters = new HashMap<>();
connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, getCapabilities);
connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.TIMEOUT.key, 10000000);
WFSDataStoreFactory dsf = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
try {
    WFSDataStore dataStore = dsf.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
    String types[] = dataStore.getTypeNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(types[i]);
        String name = types[i];
        Query query = new Query(name);
        SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(name);
        SimpleFeatureType schema = source.getSchema();
        // System.out.println(schema);
        query.setMaxFeatures(10);
        SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures(query);
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = fc.features()) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature sf = itr.next();
                System.out.println(sf);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I am getting this exception:

```
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Expected {http://www.opengis.net/wfs}WFS_Capabilities but was http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#schema
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory.parseCapabilities(WFSDataStoreFactory.java:557)
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(WFSDataStoreFactory.java:477)
    at com.hamdhan.geotooltest.controller.LayerController.TestGeoToolsRestAPI(LayerController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

The GeoTools `WFSDataStoreFactory` expects the URL you pass in to point to the `getCapabilities` request of your WFS server. You've confused it by passing in a `describeFeature` request which returns the schema of a feature collection not a capabilities document.

Simply change

```
String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeNames=districtwpc:ernakulam";
```

to

```
String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getCapabilities";
```

A couple of other points, `10000000` is a long time for a time out and will significantly slow down your program if it encounters a machine that is offline. Secondly, I notice your program is called `TestGeoToolsRestAPI` - just to note that (at this time) the OGC services such as WFS are not RESTful in any way. You will get an HTTP 200 response even on service errors, for example.